# Does html5 video support flv out of the box on mobile phones(symbian,android,iphone)?

Tags: flash, html, mobile-phones, html5-video

The purpose is to support playing flv without requiring client side script like actionscript.

Anyone knows?

Comment: I can't say for sure if it does or doesn't but I can say that Apple (iPhone) is NOT supporting flash/flv playback on their devices ... period.

Answer (score 5):

HTML5 video support is lacking at best currently. Many browser vendors each use different codecs (Safari/MS use H.264, Firefox Opera use Ogg/Theora). None of the browsers support the .FLV format to display video. .FLV and .F4V are the Flash Player's format. HTML5's primary intention is to reduce the need for plugins, so Flash Video is not part of the spec. To answer your question though: it depends on the mobile browser's implementation of the HTML5 specification and their selection of codec.

Comment: "so Flash Video is not part of the spec" - of course not, no video codec or container format is part of the spec right now; this has nothing to do with plugin politics. A user agent *could* support FLV playback in the video tag, but so far none does.

Comment: @wamp
http://diveintohtml5.org/video.html
Scroll down to the section titled "What Works on the Web."

Answer (score 1):

This code doesn't work.. video tag doesn't support flv ext

```
<video>
    <source src"yourFile.flv" type="video/flv">
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nope.

I’m not sure if any phones support FLV at all yet. It’s only really really recent Android phones that support Flash at all I think?

Comment: "I’m not sure if any phones support FLV at all yet" .. and it never will... http://www.wired.com/gadgetlab/2010/04/adobe-flash-iphone/

Comment: By “it”, you mean the iPhone? It will if enough people stop buying iPhones due to the lack of Flash.

Answer (score 0):

I can say for sure that default browsers for phones running Symbian S60 5th ed., WInMobile up to 6.5, Android up to 2.1  does not support HTML5.

Answer (score 0):

FLV is a Flash video format (or is it a container), and has nothing to do with HTML5. While a video format for HTML5 hasn't been agreed on, currently browsers support H.264 and Ogg Theora with Google recently open-sourcing the VP8 codec and packaging it up into the WebM container. Technically a browser could support flv via the HTML5 `<video>` element, but that's never going to happen. Browser support is thus:

- Firefox 3.6 - Ogg Theora
- Firefox 4.0 - Ogg Theora + WebM
- Chrome 5.0 - H.264 + Ogg Theora (WebM coming soon)
- Safari 4/5 - H.264
- Opera 10.5 - Ogg Theora (I believe WebM coming soon)
- IE9 - H.264 (supports WebM if installed by the user)

To answer your question, if you want to play .flv videos then you're stuck using Flash I'm afraid. If you want to take advantage of HTML5 video now it is possible to create an HTML5 video player that degrades to Flash support if the user doesn't have an HTML5 browser. It would mean converting your videos into H.264 and/or Ogg Theora, as well as keeping the flv ones handy, so you could potentially end up having to deal with multiple video files in different formats taking up drive space.

**EDIT:** I noticed you're referring to mobile phones, rather than desktop browsers, what I know is that Safari on iPhone supports H.264, Android supports H.264 (I'm sure WebM will make an appearance on Android devices), Windows Mobile 7 will likely support H.264. I'm not sure about the rest.

Comment: I'm dealing with real time video ,so it's impossible to convert into H.264 or whatever before hand.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this helps or not. But I've found that if the client has DIVX PLUS WEB PLAYER (free to download) installed, it plays many of the video extensions and they are all specified the same way. Below is a sample of the code that worked.

LINK: http://www.divx.com/en/software/divx-plus/web-player

```
<head>
    <!-- WEBSITE INFORMATION -->
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="description" content="DESC" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="KEYS" />

    <!-- STYLE SHEET LINKS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="css/mycss.css" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/myIcon.ico" />

    <!-- SCRIPT TO LOAD WEBSITE -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.7.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/myjs.js"></script>

    <link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
  <source src="http://www.myweb.com/video.flv" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="http://www.myweb.com/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
  <source src="http://www.myweb.com/video.avi" type="video/mp4" />
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
</body>
```

Check it out for yourselves, maybe I've just been lucky or something. But this has worked for me in the past. I don't know why, I cannot explain it, I just know it worked.